# sort multiple column file

Tags: linux, sorting, command-line

I have a file a.dat as following.

```
1 0.246102 21 1 0.0408359 0.00357267
2 0.234548 21 2 0.0401056 0.00264361
3 0.295771 21 3 0.0388905 0.00305116
4 0.190543 21 4 0.0371858 0.00427217
5 0.160047 21 5 0.0349674 0.00713894
```

I want to sort the file according to values in second column. i.e. output should look like

```
    5 0.160047 21 5 0.0349674 0.00713894
    4 0.190543 21 4 0.0371858 0.00427217
    2 0.234548 21 2 0.0401056 0.00264361
    1 0.246102 21 1 0.0408359 0.00357267
    3 0.295771 21 3 0.0388905 0.00305116
```

How can do this with command line?. I read that sort command can be used for this purpose. But I could not figure out how to use sort command for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort -k` to indicate the column you want to use:

```
$ sort -k2 file
5 0.160047 21 5 0.0349674 0.00713894
4 0.190543 21 4 0.0371858 0.00427217
2 0.234548 21 2 0.0401056 0.00264361
1 0.246102 21 1 0.0408359 0.00357267
3 0.295771 21 3 0.0388905 0.00305116
```

This makes it in this case.

For future references, note (as [indicated by 1_CR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957038/sort-multiple-column-file/19957056#comment29703669_19957056)) that you can also indicate the range of columns to be used with `sort -k2,2` (just use column 2) or `sort -k2,5` (from 2 to 5), etc.

Comment: Pls see my answer. You need to specify the end column for sorting, else it considers the entire line starting from field 2 for sorting

Comment: You can specify it, but it is not needed for many cases like this one.

Comment: thanks fedorqui, that was bloody fast answer..!! but I can accept it only after 11 minutes as required by SO rules

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need to specify the start and end fields for sorting (`2` and `2` in this case), and if you need numeric sorting, add `n`.

```
sort -k2,2n file.txt
```